# $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I have to show that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})^*=\{(\pm1,\pm1)\}$, so I thought I should be looking for elements which have inverses in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ and hopefully find more or less than 4. But I didn't succeed, so I need hints. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you not succeed in computing the units?

Comment: The only units in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ are $\pm 1, \pm X$. So this won't help here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, let's start with the polynomial ring and try to define an isomorphism to the product ring. The multiplicative identity needs to go to the multiplicative identity, for starters:
\[1 \mapsto (1,1)\]
The only remaining question is where $X$ goes. Well, we have $X^2 = 1$, so $X$ has to go to an element that squares to the identity. If it's $(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$ the homomorphism won't be injective, so it's either $(1,-1)$ or $(-1,1)$, and it doesn't really matter which:
\[X \mapsto (1,-1)\]
Now a general element of the polynomial ring can be written $a + bX$ for integers $a$ and $b$, and it'll be mapped to: \[(a + b, a - b)\]
But the difference between these two entries is $2b$, so we can never make any element of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ whose entries differ by an odd number. In particular, the proposed homomorphism does not hit $(1,0)$ and is not surjective.

Comment: I think I'd prefer an answer that was along the lines of "this ring has property P but the other ring has not-P, so they are not isomorphic" but this does seem to work.

Comment: The property you want it that $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ has a pair of orthogonal idempotents, while the quotient ring doesn’t. You see this clearly by tensoring with $\mathbb Q$, where the idempotents are $(x+1)/2$ and $(x-1)/2$.

Comment: One may also see this in a more elementary way by simply writing $f(x) = ax+b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then seeing what must occur for $f(x)^2 = f(x)$. One ends up with $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ as the only solution.

Comment: @rghthndsd the only solution other than $a=b=0$ :)

Comment: Here's another ring-theoretic property. The minimal prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ are coprime, but those of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ are not.

Comment: @Lubin As for underlying *conceptual* properties, the view of the relationship between element and ring factorizations described in my answer has much to recommend.

Answer (score 9):

$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ lacks nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: Quick note on the history, for those who come here: I originally posted this as an answer to a question that was then found to be a duplicate of this one. So I posted the same answer here. Very shortly after, a moderator merged the two questions, and deleted my only answer. (You can see it below, if your reputation is high enough.)

Answer (score 7):

A homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to specifying an element of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

A homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to specifying an element of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ *whose square equals $(1,1)$*.

What are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ whose square equals $(1,1)$? *Hint*: You've only got $4$ possibilities. So, there are $4$ homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

**Exercise**: Check that none of these homomorphisms is surjective.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Whee, universal properties :)

Comment: Those properties are no more universal than Ben's. Actually, it is the same idea.

Comment: @Tomas Yes, you're right. I typed my answer independently of Ben's answer though.

Comment: No offense! This was merely a note to the above comment, which (I now noticed) is also from Ben :)

Comment: Yes, I wondered if my comment was accurate. I stand by the "Whee", though, I like this answer better than mine :P

Comment: @Tomas OK, thanks for your comment! (It will be useful to future readers to know that the two answers are, in fact, equivalent.)

Comment: @Ben Thanks! Though it's clear from reading your answer that you had the same idea as me even though you didn't refer to it as "universal property". I think our two answers complement each other very well!

Answer (score 6):

$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ would imply (after modding out the ideal $(2)$) that $$\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X-1)^2 \cong \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2.$$The first ring has a nontrivial nilpotent element, whereas the second one does not.

Answer (score 1):

The ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-X)$ has the universal property
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},R) \cong \{a \in R : a^2=a\},$$
and the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ has the universal property
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1),R) \cong \{a \in R : a^2=1\}.$$
Thus, if $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ were isomorphic, this would imply that every ring $R$ has the same numbers of idempotents and of involutions. This is of course wrong, consider $R=\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ for instance; this ring has $4$ idempotents, but only $1$ involution.

Answer (score 0):

By below Lemma $\,\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2\!-\!1)\cong\:\! \Bbb Z\!\times\! \Bbb Z\,$ $\Rightarrow\, \overbrace{(x\!-\!1)\,a(x)\!+\!(x\!+\!1)\,b(x) = 1}^{\large x-1,\ x+1\ \ {\rm are\ \color{#0a0}{comaximal}\ in}^{\phantom{}}\ \Bbb Z[x]}\ \ \smash{\overset{x\,\to\, 1}\Longrightarrow}\ \  \bbox[4px,border:1px solid #0a0]{2\mid 1}\,$ in $\Bbb Z$

---

**Idea** $ $ proper factorizations of $\,R/f\,$ $\rm\small\color{#f60}{induce}$ coprime $\small\rm\color{#0a0}{(i.e. comaximal)}$ proper
factorizations of $f\,$ by

**Lemma** $  $ If $\ \begin{align}f\in R\,\ \rm  a\ UFD,\\ {\rm rings}\ G,H\!\neq 0\end{align}\,\ $ then $\, \begin{align} R/f\,\ &\cong\,\ G\!\times\! H\\ \color{#f60}{\bf\large  \Rightarrow} f\ \  &\!\!=\ g\ h\end{align}\, $ with $\ \begin{align} &\color{#0a0}{(g)\!+\!(h)=(1)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!}\\ &\,(g),\, (h)\neq\:\! (1)\end{align}\,$ for some $\,g,h\in R^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!$

**Proof** $\ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3509367/242) for a simple $\,4\,$ line proof.